# Git - checkout branch - would be over written by merge

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm trying to switch to a branch:
`git branch new-ui`

When I do this I get an error that a file would be over written by a merge.
This file does not exist anymore. When I do a pull from the current branch the file does not come down.I push and get message everything is up-to-date.

How do I resolve this? Currently stuck and cannot switch branches.

Answer (score 2):

Issue the command

```
git status
```

It will probably tell you that a file has been deleted, as an uncommitted change. Did you try committing?

Also, did you delete the file with `git rm`, or with `rm`?

Comment: rm. thanks. that helped me find the issue. I had many tests that I deleted just for a special branch. hadn't done git add -A and then git commit. Did those commands and pushed, then I was able to switch branches. +1 and answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend another useful command,
git stash

which temporarily stores your WIP(Work In Progress) changes and makes your repo clean.
If you'd like your WIP back, try
git stash apply  or  git stash pop